# Tikz externalize does not work although shell escape is enabled

Tags: latex, pdflatex, tikz, miktex

I am using TexStudio with Miktex on my thesis and need to externalize all the tikz graphics created. I worked through a lot of posts but couldn't figure out why i cannot externalize my code. I use `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex` to compile but also tried with write18.

This is the output of one of the figure logs:

```
The command '\includegraphics []{\AM@currentdocname }' has been     optimized away.
Use '/tikz/external/optimize=false' to disable this.
! Undefined control sequence.
\AM@getpagecount ...ource {\AM@currentdocname@fix 
                                              }\edef \AM@pagecount     {\the...
l.181 \vorspann

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 46796 strings out of 492970
 976398 string characters out of 3126594
 1219813 words of memory out of 3000000
 49867 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 567782 words of font info for 61 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 72i,9n,84p,9134b,280s stack positions out of     5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

and of the main tex file :

```
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape    -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figures/Masterarbeit-figure87"    "\def\t    ikzexternalrealjob{Masterarbeit}\input{Masterarbeit}"' ========
\openout3 = `Masterarbeit.auxlock'.

runsystem(pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode    -jobname
"figures/Masterarbeit-figure87" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Masterarbeit}   \input{
Masterarbeit}")...executed.

\openout3 = `Masterarbeit.auxlock'.


! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape    -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "figures/Masterarbeit-figure87"    "\def\tikz
externalrealjob{Masterarbeit}\input{Masterarbeit}"' did NOT result in a    usable 
output file 'figures/Masterarbeit-figure87' (expected one of    .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.p
ng:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex,    this is '
pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or    something lik
e that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found    in 'fig
ures/Masterarbeit-figure87.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to    typeset the p
icture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
```

Also i might add that i can see the pdf file in my windows file system for a fraction of second before it disappears again

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem?

Comment: How exactly did your call with `write18` look like? For miktex the correct syntax should be something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489/how-can-i-enable-write-18-on-a-miktex-installation#comment75093_37489

Comment: I figured while creating a MWE... todo package causes problems...without todonotes it works:)...thank you anyway